# Publishing Vb.net10 Application

Tags: vb.net, exe, publishing

I developed this software application with VB.net and Microsoft Access. The software works fine. publishing this applciation has been a huge problem for me. even though it seem to have published fine, it does not seem to recognise my access Database and props up error everytime and everywhere the database is called and used within the program. How can i overcome this problem please.

Comment: What's your connection string? and what error pops up?

Comment: Unhandled Exception has occured in your application. The "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: make sure the released version is compiled it as a 32 bit app, and that Interop.ADODB.dll and Interop.JRO.dll are distributed with your project

Comment: Thanks Rob. I will try that. Does that mean therefore that the App would not work on a 64bit? i will really love for this to work on 64bit machine.

Comment: @Joseph I just got back home, thus, I just replied :) I encountered this problem a gazillion times. I posted an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got back from somewhere, anyways... I actually had problems with Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 especially in a 64 bit machine. This is because Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is designed as a 32 bit component. If you compile your solution as AnyCpu, it shouldn't work since an x64 process cannot load x86 component. So you have 2 options.

1) Change the compiling to 32 bit mode.

2) Use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider instead of Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0. This uses .accdb instead of .mdb. This is more future proof since the last time I heard, 2003 office won't be supported anymore :)